# JavaFX 2.0 memory leak on creating multiple scenes

Tags: memory-leaks, garbage-collection, javafx

I created a sample application that provokes a memory leak.

The problem is that I need to "reload" scenes. If I have two scenes (Bar and Foo) with one button each (ButtonBar and ButtonFoo), the buttons changes the current scene creating a new one.
If I stay clicking ButtonBar and ButtonFoo for 5 minutes (or less), the memory consumption of that simple program gets higher and higher.

Bar.java

```
public class Bar implements Initializable {

@FXML
private Label label;

@FXML
private void toFoo(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        Button button = (Button) event.getSource();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Foo.fxml"));
        Stage currentStage = (Stage) button.getScene().getWindow();
        currentStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Bar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}    
}
```

The Foo.java is the same changing de fxml loading.

The fxml contains only one button:

```
<Button id="buttonBar" layoutX="126" layoutY="90" text="Bar!" onAction="#toFoo" fx:id="buttonBar" />
```

Is there a real memory-leak problem? Does anyone knows another way to do this? I want that this app stay alive and doing changes forever, like a service.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm with a similar problem.

When i move the mouse on scene. The memory usage increases and **never** down.

I believe this is associated with mouse events.

Good Luck!

Comment: Yep. Any interaction at all with the Scene Builder grows memory exponentially...this is the latest version downloaded from Java's site. WTF is going on here? This is 2 years after your post...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the memory leaks, but for performance reasons I would avoid the repeated loading of the resource.

What I do is keep that root Parent in a variable and add it to a scene, or in my case to a specific part of another scene as needed, updating the values via a static method of the controller class.

I have several of these preloaded scenes,  that update a part of a bigger scene every time the user selects certain values from a list.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try FX8. An amount of fixes for memory leaks have been made there already.

In case you can't update to the latest version of JavaFX though, I suggest you do not use `onAction="#toFoo"` in FXML.

Rather, declare an event handler and call the following: `buttonBar.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, declaredEventHandler);`.

Release then the event handler before exiting your current screen: `buttonBar.removeEventHandler(declaredEventHandler);`